# Angular reformat an array

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an array looking like this: <sup>[[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArNSo.png)]</sup>

```
   ▼[Array(5)]
       ▼0: Array(5)
            0: pfQ1A3M0S1V6icGcLKTIdBoIWA42
            1: 0rrfZUw6RAcSxoAknCJJ6GGgB9y1
            2: 6RXWFEsEMdZWJTeUN3wMAj1PzYu2
            3: QK39c753XUP7MbqVbMObSYPdmKB2
            4: r8sN2eYtBTSvFSVunQQ71nxAGbO2
            length: 5
           ▶__proto__: Array(0)
        length: 1
       ▶__proto_: Array(0)

   ▼(2) [Array(5), "XG9oznIXpucqPFekDrGm6ixpctt2"]
       ▶0: (5) ["0rrfZUw6RAcSxoAknCJJ6GGgB9y1", "0rrfZUw6RAcSxoAknCJJ6GGgB9y1", …] // From first array
        1: "XG9oznIXpucqPFekDrGm6ixpctt2"
        length: 2
       ▶__proto:__ Array(0)
```

This is my code:

```
this.old = this.checFilter.map(r=>r.userId);
this.checked.push(this.old);
console.log(this.checked);
```

As you can see, I have 5 arrays in first array. And then I am pushing it to an other array. Result is showing 2 arrays after push. But I need to have an array with 6 entries as a result.

Comment: Please provide your variables as text, not as images.

Comment: You are pushing the new value on the wrong level …

Comment: You do not have *5 arrays in the first array*. You have an array with 5 element. I'm assuming you want 6 element in your array ?

Comment: You can use `concat`

Answer (score 1):

You must use concat function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat

```
this.old = this.checFilter.map(r=>r.userId);
this.checked = this.checked.concat(this.old);
console.log(this.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

This pushes each value directly into the array instead of the whole array as 1 value, but be careful. This way of doing it **mutates** your array.

```
this.checFilter.map(r => this.checked.push(r.userId));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with your answer , so that others can learn as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flat your arrays:

```
arr.flatMap(f=> f);
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [

  ['pfQ1A3M0S1V6icGcLKTIdBoIWA42',
    '0rrfZUw6RAcSxoAknCJJ6GGgB9y1',
    '6RXWFEsEMdZWJTeUN3wMAj1PzYu2',
    'QK39c753XUP7MbqVbMObSYPdmKB2',
    'r8sN2eYtBTSvFSVunQQ71nxAGbO2',],

  'XG9oznIXpucqPFekDrGm6ixpctt2'
]

const result = arr.flatMap(f=> f);
console.log(result);
```